# Do Token Creatures go to the graveyard?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Does a token creature when it dies satisfy the criteria of [Fresh Meat](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFresh%20Meat%5d)? Text of card as follows:

> Create a 3/3 green Beast creature token for each creature put into your graveyard from the battlefield this turn.

Comment: Tokens cease to exist (through State Based Actions) once they leave the battlefield, but they do reach the graveyard first.

Answer (score 8):

Yes. Per Comprehensive Rules:

> 110.5e A token is subject to anything that affects permanents in general or that affects the token’s card type or subtype. (...)

So the token is put in the graveyard like other creatures. There is one difference, but this doesn't matter for Fresh Meat:

> 110.5f A token that’s in a zone other than the battlefield ceases to exist. (...) (Note that if a token changes zones, applicable triggered abilities will trigger before the token ceases to exist.)

It won't be in the graveyard at the time Fresh Meat resolves, but it will still count as a creature put into your graveyard.

Comment: There's even a ruling on the Gatherer page that explicitly covers this "6/1/2011  Fresh Meat counts all creatures you owned that went to the graveyard this turn, including creature tokens that entered the battlefield under your control and nontoken creatures you owned but didn’t control."

Answer (score 2):

Essentially, it does go to the graveyard, but instantaneously disappears. It also cannot return to the battlefield as said in the comments.

Note: it is instantaneously *removed from play*, not *sent into exile*.

Fresh Meat, however, does work in this case: whether or not the token creature is in the graveyard right now, it *was* technically sent into the graveyard. Because Fresh Meat does not require you to return it, there is nothing wrong with placing a 3/3 token onto the battlefield for it.

Comment: Your second paragraph seems to say the token can head to the graveyard and be returned to play, but the rules don't permit that (it instantly vanishes from the graveyard as soon as it reaches it) but you acknowledge those yourself, so I'm not sure how to interpret that paragraph.

Comment: There. Changed it.

Comment: Ok, reading that I think you are mistaken about token interactions -- it won't ever return to the battlefield even if it's an effect that would try to "flicker" it to and from the graveyard. See [token rule 110.5g](https://mtg.gamepedia.com/Token#Rules): *"110.5g A token that has left the battlefield can’t move to another zone or come back onto the battlefield. If such a token would change zones, it remains in its current zone instead. It ceases to exist the next time state-based actions are checked; see rule 704."* This prevents the "bring it back" part of that ability, the token stays put.

Comment: @doppelgreener, Re "*it instantly vanishes from the graveyard as soon as it reaches it*", Not quite. It's SBAs that cause it to vanish, so it can stick around for a little while. That said, it's hard to come up with practical difference between the two.