# What happens to token creatures and planeswalker creatures that die?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

The [Allied Fires Challenger Deck](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/feature/challenger-decks-2020-02-15) from Magic 2020 contains [Sarkhan the Masterless](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSarkhan%20the%20Masterless%5d), who can both create dragon tokens, and turn other planeswalkers into dragons.

If a planeswalker that becomes a dragon dies, does it go into the graveyard? What about the dragon tokens that Sarkhan creates?

Comment: Just a heads up here: due to a [recent banning](https://magic.wizards.com/en/articles/archive/news/june-1-2020-banned-and-restricted-announcement) you will not be allowed to use that deck in any competitive MtG events. It's still absolutely fine for playing casually with your friends of course :-)

Answer (score 2):

If a planeswalker becomes a creature, it acts as a creature in every way, including being able to kill it and send it to the graveyard with normal damage.

This means that if you activate [Sarkhan the Masterless](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSarkhan%20the%20Masterless%5d)'s +1 ability, then all your planswalkers (including Sarkhan) could be killed with something like [Doom Blade](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bDoom%20Blade%5d) or [Flame Lash](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bFlame%20Lash%5d). It will be sent to the graveyard just like any other creature.

When a token creature dies, it does go to the graveyard, but then ceases to exist the next time state-based actions are checked. You can see more details about that [here](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/42524/do-token-creatures-go-to-the-graveyard?noredirect=1&lq=1).